# Prevent shared Data Extensions from being updated in child

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Shared Data Extensions can be hidden from specific BUs using permissions of single Shared DE folders. But can shared Data Extensions be set to read-only in any BU other than ENT? Ultimately the data is "owned" by ENT and updated by Automations running there - hence updating the shared DEs from children will lead to inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using Filtered Data Extensions, as these are always read-only. It requires us to use filters instead of SQL queries in Automation Studio, when distributing data from single global data extension to a number of shared data extensions across child BUs. However in our use case, this is sufficient.